# Projections on nested collections

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have three entities Topic, Subject and Category. How can I prefetch id and name columns for each of the entity while retrieving all the categories with subjects and topics? I don't need other fields since it affects the performance.

```
@Entity
class Topic{
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  ...
  //other fields
} 

@Entity
class Subject{
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  ...
 //other fields

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<Topic> topics;
}

@Entity
class Category{
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  ...
  //other fields
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<Subject> subjects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a result class on top of the projection itself as it eases the result set handling. The ResultClass needs to have a constructor with relevant query result fields and you have to use the fully qualified name in the query itself.

```
select new org.mypkg.ResultClass(c.id, c.name, s.id, s.name, t.id, t.name)
from Category c
  inner join c.subjects s
  inner join s.topics
```

Then you simply:

```
List<ResultClass> results = em.createQuery(query).list();
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem: I'll have to group subjects and topics manually afterwards